# How to implement SVM algorithm from scratch in a programming language?

Tags: machine-learning, implementation, support-vector-machine

I'm a computer scientist who's studying support vector machines (SVMs) in a machine learning course. I have some understanding of how SVMs are designed, thanks to [16. Learning: Support Vector Machines - MIT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PwhiWxHK8o). However, what I'm not understanding is the transition from the optimization problem of the Lagrangian function to its implementation in any programming language. Basically, what I need to understand is how to build, from scratch, the decision function, given a training set. In particular, how do I find Lagrange multipliers in order to know which points are to be considered to define support vectors and the decision function?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: We're you ever able to answer your question because I have arrived at a similar point?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this repository:

https://github.com/arkm97/svm-from-scratch/blob/master/SVM_from_scratch.ipynb

I will try to reverse engineering that concept:

So firstly there is issue for **DataCleaning**(removing 0,values, serialize, normalize)

normalizing dataset (replaced by its difference from the mean)

```
credit_df_norm = (credit_df - credit_df.mean())/(credit_df.std())
```

Divide dataset into Train & Test:

```
train_df = credit_df_norm.drop(target, axis=1).loc[:training_points]
train_target = credit_df_norm[target].replace(0, -1).loc[:training_points]
```

And here is starting the clue of that algorithms (with maths etc.)

> given data points $\vec x_j \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times N}$ and targets
> $y_j = \pm 1$, where $j = 1, \dots, M$, find the maximum-margin
> hyperplane that separates the two classes ($y_j = 1$ and $y_j = -1$).
>
> Let $\vec w$ be the vector normal to the hyperplane. We want to find
> $\vec w$ that satisfies
>
> $$ y_j (\vec w \cdot \vec x_j + b) \geq 1 $$ The dual formulation of
> the above is equivalent to maximizing the following over the
> multipliers $\vec \alpha$:
>
> $$ L(\vec \alpha) = \vec y \cdot \vec \alpha  - \frac 1 2  \vec \alpha
> > K \vec \alpha^T$$ subject to the constraints $\sum_{j=1}^M \alpha_j =
> > 0$ and $y_j \alpha_j \geq 0$. The matrix $K$ defines the kernel of the
> SVM; I've chosen $K_{jk} = k(\vec x_j, \vec x_k) = \vec x_j \cdot \vec
> > x_k$. The parameters of the plane are recovered from $\vec w = \vec
> > \alpha \cdot \vec x$ and $b = y_j = \vec w \cdot \alpha_j$ for $j$
> such that $\alpha_j \neq 0$

Let's divide it to the single factors:

we need to find [maximum-margin-hyperplane](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-maximum-margin-hyperplane-in-SVM) for separate into two classes:
Separation cause SVN is classification - so we need to classify elements into categories.

= 1

= −1

This pattern allow to find hyperplane(?)

(⃗ ⋅⃗ +)≥1

The next pattern:

(⃗ )=⃗ ⋅⃗ −12⃗ >⃗

The author for kernel SVN choose those pattern:

=(⃗ ,⃗ )=⃗ ⋅>⃗

And the parameters for plane are here:

⃗ =>⃗ ⋅⃗  and ==⃗ ⋅ for  such that ≠0

Reference:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0471.pdf

---

In this line are added the kernel

Popular kernels are:

- Polynomial Kernel,
- Gaussian Kernel,
- Radial Basis Function (RBF),
- Laplace RBF Kernel,
- Sigmoid Kernel,
- Anove RBF Kernel

  k_value = np.array(train_df @ train_df.T + np.identity(len(train_target))*1e-12)

The structure of k_value (kernel matrix) is an array.

[image]

Next there is use of [cholesky decomposition—cholesky](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cholesky-decomposition-matrix-decomposition/) - which is next complicated concept.

```
np.linalg.cholesky(k_value)
```

Next some bits of data converting:

alpha = cp.Variable(shape=train_target.shape)

beta = cp.multiply(alpha, train_target) # to simplify notation

```
K = cp.Parameter(shape=k_value.shape, PSD=True, value=k_value)

# objective function
obj = .5 * cp.quad_form(beta, K) - np.ones(alpha.shape).T @ alpha

# constraints
const = [np.array(train_target.T) @ alpha == 0,
        -alpha <= np.zeros(alpha.shape),
        alpha <= 10*np.ones(shape=alpha.shape)]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), const)
```

The next step is recreate the hyperplane:

```
w = np.multiply(train_target, alpha.value).T @ train_df
S = (alpha.value > 1e-4).flatten()
b = train_target[S] - train_df[S] @ w
b = b[0]
# b = np.mean(b)
```

And finally - the classification and evaluation:

```
def classify(x):
    result = w @ x + b
    return np.sign(result)

correct = 0
incorrect = 0
validation_set = credit_df_norm.drop(target, axis=1)
predictions = []
for i, x in validation_set.iterrows():
    my_svm = classify(x)
    if my_svm==credit_df_norm[target].replace(0, -1)[i]: correct +=1
    else: incorrect +=1
    predictions.append(my_svm)
predictions = np.array(predictions)


print(f"fraction correct: {correct/(correct + incorrect)}")
```

---

That was the more detailed implementation - for shorcut there is an interesting article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/svm-and-kernel-svm-fed02bef1200

There are existing function from another library - that can be reused in simple manner:

```
# Fitting SVM to the Training set
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', C = 0.1, gamma = 0.1)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

# use seaborn plotting defaults
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
```

Visualized Dataset:
[image]

Dataset after apply hyperplanes:
[image]